# Could not execute build using gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'

Tags: android, gradle

I'm new to android development and I've downloaded Android SDK 4.2 and receiving the error:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org     /distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'. from the event log
```

I have tried many of the solutions here for similar error messages:

File - Invalidate Caches/restart - Invalidate and Restart.  Then shutting down AS and renaming the .gradle folder in c/users/myname to old.gradle and restarting.

renaming the version number in build.gradle 
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+' to 0.8.+

renaming version in gradle-wrapper.properties services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip to 1.10

uninstalling AS twice.

Some of the solutions I simple don't understand and for those that I do understand it seems I've tried them all.

I read to try another version of gradle 1.9, but don't where to begin.  Are there versions like 1.9.1, 1.9.2..etc?

Any help?

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
     }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

 allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

Comment: Lastest version of AS is [0.4.6](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-4-6) try with that version.

Comment: When I look here it only has 4.2.http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: Either install from the link I mentioned, or go to "Help > Check update" to get the latest version.

Comment: Studio 0.4.6 is in Canary Channel for improvements. But the issue you have doesn't related to the Studio version. Please include your gradle wrapper and build.gradle file, I want to have look in to them once.

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Check your gradle installation at `C:\Users\yourusername\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.9-all\3jdgemv0iv8uqohg3kcp2o88r1\gradle-1.9` is it there or not ?

Comment: the gradle-1.9 folder is there. When I did the installation I placed android studio under c/program files.  It also placed these additional directories(.gradle, etc) under c/users.  Would that cause a problem?

Comment: Studio path is not a problem just check the complete path of gradle in my comments whether it exists or not ?

Comment: It does exist. thanks

Comment: Is it working fine now if not check whether the URL in gradle wrapper is able to download the gradle zip, Studio should automatically download this for you if it is accessible form your machine.

Comment: I've tried everything and I'm at the point of complete frustration.  The reason I went this route was I couldn't get around all the bugs/issues with Google maps api v2 in eclipse and now I can't even start a project in AS.  I wish my boss had asked me to do this app for Windows Phone.  I would have been done months ago.

Comment: Please attach the output from your Gradle Console view after seeing this problem.

Comment: I finally got it working.  I honestly don't know what resolved it from all the things (ALOT OF THINGS) I have tried since last checking this post of mine.  I wish I had something to post to help anyone else who may have the same issue as me.  I'm just glad its working.  Thanks to all who have attempted to help me. This can be closed.

Comment: I thought the latest Gradle distribution is 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as described at the top while following a course on Udemy. I was able to run my project on Android, but not Desktop. After messing around a lot, here is the solution that worked for me (n.b. I am a noob, so apologies for the simplicity of my answer:

with Project view (towards upper left, may be set to "Android":

go to gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties and change the gradle distribution to "gradle-2.10-all.zip

then go to build.gradle and change "dependencies{classpath..." to "'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'"

if you continue to get errors, you may need to return to the build.gradle and delete:

```
    jcenter()
    google()
```

near the top. Finally, ensure you are using the correct path for your assets by going to:

Launcher Options(where you select Android or Desktop deployment)>Edit Configurations

under working directory, set the path to android>assets

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but what I did was

1. To go to the [Gradle Repo](http://services.gradle.org/) and download the zip file specified in the wrapper.
2. Paste in the folder C:/User/youraccount/.gradle/wrapper/dist/weirdfoldername/
3. open the android studio go to File > settings > gradle
4. Make sure use default gradle wrapper is active and then check offline work
5. Restart the studio

Worked for me. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this error if you are experiencing Internet issues. (In my browser, some webpages worked, some didn't.) Resetting my modem resolved the gradle error for me.