# Gradle distribution not exist

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I updated my android studio to 3.3.2 recently and now i am getting and error that gradle build gradle-4.10.1 does not exist. It says distribution url is https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip does not exist and i have checked that my internet connection is working fine.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992309/could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution-http-services-gradle-org-di) can help.